# UK visa from Germany as an Indian Passport Holder

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, germany

I am an Indian Passport holder with a fiktionsbeseinigung (temporary visa) living in Germany past 8 months wanting to travel to the UK for 10 days to visit my uncle. I came to Germany for a job but have recently become unemployed thanks to corona and I want to visit my family in the UK and it has been really tough living here through the corona.

I have a sponsorship letter from my uncle and an invitation letter with his council tax and bill for me. I have around 6k pounds as my savings from my previous job. Is this sufficient to get me a UK tourist visa from Germany?

Also, do I have to show that he is sponsoring me and put in the exact amount he would be spending on me daily ? or can I just show my savings and his sponsor letter with documents and I should be good to go?
Need urgent help

Comment: Unemployed and visiting uncle may trigger a flag: you may want to remain in UK. When your temporary visa ends? How you a plan on what to do after that? I would push documents on that direction: so reasons you will not remain in UK.You have enough to live and you will do a short trip, so I think money is not an important factor (but it for wiliness to immigrate). But on such period, I do not think we can answer properly. Possibly also UK is much more strict

Comment: @user113178 Savings of £6k are more than sufficient for a 10 day trip, therefore you don’t need to submit anything other than an invitation letter from your uncle, plus proof of his immigration status in the UK. **But** your big problem is proving a compelling reason to leave at the end of your stay. Applying for a visitor visa as an unemployed temporary resident in Germany who has family in the UK is very likely to be a huge red flag. Better to defer your trip until you have a new job, IMHO

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.